# How can I make a Soap client with dynamic SSL authentification?

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, soap-client, pfx

I just have this code for calling a web service with a PFX file

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", pathPFX);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", pass);
System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");
QName serviceName = new QName("www.example.org", "example");

//QName for Port As defined in wsdl.
QName portName = new QName("www.example.org", "exampleSOAP");

// Create a dynamic Service instance
Service service = Service.create(serviceName);

// Add a port to the Service
service.addPort(portName, SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING, endpointAddress);

//Create a dispatch instance
Dispatch<SOAPMessage> dispatch = service.createDispatch(portName, SOAPMessage.class, Service.Mode.MESSAGE); 

MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();

SOAPMessage request = factory.createMessage();

// Object for message parts
SOAPPart sp = request.getSOAPPart();
StreamSource prepMsg = new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(pathXML));
sp.setContent(prepMsg);

// Save message
request.saveChanges();

SOAPMessage reply = null;
boolean success = true;
String response = "";
try {
    //Invoke Endpoint Operation and read response
    reply = dispatch.invoke(request);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    reply.writeTo(out);
    creaXMLResponse(out.toString());
} 
catch (WebServiceException wse)
{
  wse.printStackTrace();
    success = false;
}
```

And it's just working fine, but now I have to use a different PFX file for a different client they will be running at the same tomcat.

Using this code will make me restart the tomcat to use a different PFX, so I need to create a dynamic way to choose the pfx as a Keystore but without using a JKS file(the number of clients will increase and I can't be creating a new JKS everytime) ??

Note: I've been reading about using a Keystore and a SSLContext but I dont know how to link them to my actual code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As the name implies, a keystore can store multiple keys, not just one. So common approach is to store all keys required to handshake with all servers in the same keystore.

Check the keytool manual page, there's a lot of tutorial on this